# numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopErrorというエラーメッセージ

Tags: python, pandas

折れ線グラフを描画したいですけど、以下のエラーメッセージが出ました。
どう書き換えたらいいですか？
ご教示いただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U7'), dtype('float64')) -> None
```

**現状のコード:**

```
ifile = pd.read_csv(r"来客数.csv", header=0)
print(ifile)
# ファイル名から画像作成日となる日付を抽出
date = ifile[-16:-8]

# そして作成した画像ファイルを置いておくディレクトリを事前に自動作成
odir = "../fig/"+date
os.makedirs(odir, exist_ok=True)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopErrorというエラーメッセージ」はコードのどの行で発生しましたか？

Comment: odir = "../fig/"+date　の行です

Comment: それはどのような処理を期待してますか？「作成した画像ファイルを置いておくディレクトリを事前に自動作成」ということだけど, 10種類の日付があれば 10のディレクトリーを作成する？

Comment: `ifile`という変数には`pd.read_csv(r"来客数.csv", header=0)`で読み取った`"来客数.csv"`の内容全体が`pandas.DataFrame`として格納されていることと、`date = ifile[-16:-8]`という処理は`ifile`というDataFrameの最終行から数えて先頭方向に16行遡った行から8行分を抽出して`date`という変数に **DataFrameとして** 格納する処理であることを認識していますか？ 1つの文字列`"../fig/"`と8行分のデータが存在する`pandas.DataFrame`を`+`だけで連結するような単純な処理は存在しないでしょう。`date = ifile[-16:-8]`の後で`date`に何が入っているのか`print(date)`で確認してみることをお勧めします。また`date`のような短く標準的なモジュール名/メソッド名にも使われるような名前の変数は問題の元になるので使わない方が良いでしょう。

Comment: `ifile['date'].apply(lambda d: os.makedirs(f"../fig/{d}", exist_ok=True))`

Answer (score 0):

質問者さんのやりたい事ができているかは分かりませんが、下記コードでエラー`numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U7'), dtype('float64')) -> None`は解消されるかと思います。

```
odir = "../fig/" + date.astype('str')
```

文字列同士の連結になるように修正しました。